# Are babies turned upside down after birth?

Tags: breathing, position, birth, buttocks

I haven't attended a birth yet, and I heard or saw on some TV show that babies are turn upside down by the doctor and / or slapped in the butt to force them to cry, with the intention of make them start breathing.

Is this a legit medical procedure?

Comment: No, don't assist a birth. If you want to be a doctor or nurse then go to school. Here is what I turned up from a quick search, El Pais,https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/03/06/inenglish/1520334601_183672.html

Comment: The above is just my opinion. Others here may have additional information or advice for you.

Comment: @gordon yes, we agree, I would never try to. I mean in an extreme case if I would be in a remote place, but probably it is not likely happen really

Comment: That's an old practice discarded years ago. No one trained the last 50 years holds babies upside down or slaps them anywhere. In most cases the baby will begin breathing on its own without intervention. Take a course on childbirth to learn what steps to take if more is needed.

Comment: Frankly, I don’t understand why this was closed. It’s not asking for personal medical advice, it’s about whether a practice is common, and @CareyGregory ‘s answer would be a perfectly valid answer on this.

Comment: @Narusan `"If I ever happen to assist a birth, what should I do about the kid getting oxygen? Or should I do anything at all?"` -- That's clearly a request for medical advice and it's not as simple as it might appear.

Comment: @Narusan Okay, I voted to reopen.